# Is enable_if only C++11?

Tags: c++

Looking on the C++ reference website for enable_if, it is said to be only a C++11 feature.

However, I compiled my own version of enable_if using the GCC compiler on the C++98 type, which worked perfectly and seemed to be able to work for any version of C++ (1 is printed):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace egg
    {
    template<bool B,
        typename T = void>
        struct enable_if
        {
        };

    template<typename T>
        struct enable_if<true, T>
        {
        typedef T type;
        };
    }

int main()
    {
    egg::enable_if<1 == 1, int>::type x = 1;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
```

Am I right in saying the enable_if is effectively a feature for any C++ version but was only introduced into the C++ standard or is there another reason for this?

Comment: They added it in C++11. You are right on the fact that it doesn't need any new language feature, in fact it was available in Boost way before C++11 was approved.

Comment: `enable_if` and the other template metaprogramming/type-traits APIs (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) don't require any compiler magic/implementation so if you do manage to make your own, it will work in whatever version of C++ you use. With the exception of the ones like `is_move_constructible` which require C++11's move constructors and R-Value references.

Comment: This pretty good reference states it's available since c++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: And even if you are forced into C++98/C++03 do not implement them yourself (if not for learning purposes), the odds are Boost has got them.

Comment: Since C++14 the helper `std::enable_if_t` can be used instead of `typename std::enable_if<>::type`. The same goes for other `type_trait`s.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - that was the one I used to confirm it was from C++11 ! :) great website imo

Answer (score 7):

`enable_if` was added to the standard in C++11([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)).  It does not rely on any C++11 standard features and so it code be coded by yourself in C++03 as you can see from this possible implementation

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

This is just using [template metaprograming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) and [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

You could also use [`boost::enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/enable_if.html) instead of writing your own which is also C++98/03 compatible.