Eliminate functions from template class in C++03
I am stuck with a C++03 compiler and am trying to eliminate functions from a (Smart Pointer) template class for the type 'void'.
An MRE (all non-essential information stripped from the class):
template<typename T> struct EnableIfNotVoid { typedef T type; };
template<> struct EnableIfNotVoid<void> {};

template<typename T> class SmartPtr
{
    public:
        template<typename U = T>
        typename EnableIfNotVoid<U>::type &operator *(void) const
        {
            return *content;
        }

    private:
        T* content;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    SmartPtr<int> works;
    SmartPtr<void> noWork;
    int& i = *works;
}

This works flawlessly when running it through a C++11 compiler (for which I wouldn't need the class to begin with), but when trying to compile it with the C++03 compiler I am stuck with, I get the error default template arguments may not be used in function templates.
Other things I've tried (and the errors the compiler is throwing my way):
Without default argument: no match for 'operator*' in '*works'
template<typename U>
typename EnableIfNotVoid<U>::type &operator *(void) const
{
    return content;
}

Without template: no type named 'type' in 'struct EnableIfNotVoid<void>'
typename EnableIfNotVoid<T>::type &operator *(void) const
{
    return content;
}

Without SFINAE (for completeness sake): forming reference to void
T &operator *(void) const
{
    return *content;
}

I'd like to avoid having to specialize the entire class (which is rather sizeable) only to 'leave out' the two small functions and would really appreciate it, if there was some smarter way to do this.

Don't paraphrase error messages, post them exactly how the compiler outputs with error locations. A [mre] should be posted so we know what T and data are in the second snippet.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637999/2527795

Why don't you make it like boost? ... https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/boost/core/enable_if.hpp

SFINAE in the function type exists only since C++11. You need to do it in the template parameters instead.

@user17732522 That...will be difficult, considering the type of the functions (which are the * and -> operators). Those don't take parameters by definition, if I'm not mistaken.

@RefugnicEternium No, I mean the substitution error must appear in the template-head, for example like template<typename U = T, typename enable_if<!is_same<U, void>::value, void*>::type = 0> where you can implement enable_if and same_as exactly as in C++11.

@ÖöTiib I am trying to do it like Boost. The error messages I am getting while trying to apply the concept are listed above.

@user17732522 ...that I haven't tried yet.

@user17732522 Same as before. default template arguments may not be used in function templates

@RefugnicEternium Oh right, I forgot that those weren't allowed before C++11 either. Hm, I really started with C++ after C++11, so my memory of how it was done before is a bit foggy. Let me think again..

Couldn't you just specialize for void with no implementation ? like template<> struct SmartPtr<void> { };

@edrezen, I COULD, if that was all there was to the actual class. Thing is, the minimal reproducable example has been stripped of everything that's not directly related to the issue at hand. And I'd REALLY like to avoid having to copy the entire class sans the two methods causing the problem.

@RefugnicEternium, Ok then. What about abstracting common methods in a base class and defining methods for non void type in an inherited class and nothing for void template specialization ? Something like this

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I amended my examples to be based on the MRE and moved it to the top. Hopefully this improves clarity.

It does. You aldready had my vote. I can delete the obsolete comments

Approach with slightly extended specialized helper. Helper class provides return type alias which should be always valid to avoid breaking declarations. Dummy parameter delays function instantiation until operator * is actually used. Static assert from boost triggers reasonably meaningful compilation error if operator * is used in void smart pointer.
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template<typename T>
struct SmartPtrImpl
{
    typedef T & Reference;

    template<typename Dummy>
    static Reference Deref(T * ptr)
    {
        return * ptr;
    }
};

template<>
struct SmartPtrImpl<void>
{
    typedef void Reference;

    template<typename Dummy>
    static Reference Deref(void *)
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == sizeof(Dummy)), "SmartPtr<void> does not support dereference");
        return;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class SmartPtr
{
    public: typedef SmartPtrImpl<T> Impl;

    protected: T * m_ptr;

    public: SmartPtr(void): m_ptr() {}

    public: typename Impl::Reference
    operator *(void) const
    {
        return Impl::template Deref<int>(m_ptr);
    }
    // other stuff...
};

int main()
{
    SmartPtr<int> works; *works;
    SmartPtr<void> noWork; // *noWork;
}

online compiler
Uncommenting // *noWork; triggers static assertion:

error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE'
23 |                 BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((0 == sizeof(Dummy)), "SmartPtr does not support dereference");


That's clever, alright. If I understand correctly, this is akin to a partial class specialization, which is what I would've preferred to use from the get go anyway. Unfortunately, my compiler doesn't seem to like Boost very much, but there's ways around that.

A possibility is to put all the common methods (i.e. for all possible types T) in a base class SmartPtrBase and then define a subclass SmartPtr inheriting from it and providing methods for only allowed types; one has just to provide an empty specialization for void for this subclass:

template<typename T>
class SmartPtrBase
{
public:

    void foo () {};
    void bar () {};

protected:
    T* content;
};

template<typename T> 
class SmartPtr : public SmartPtrBase <T>
{
public:
    
    T& operator *(void) const
    {
        return * (this->content);
    }
};

template<> 
class SmartPtr<void>  : public SmartPtrBase <void>
{
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    SmartPtr<int>  works;
    SmartPtr<void> noWork;

    works.foo();
    noWork.foo();
    
    *works;
//  *noWork;   /* error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'SmartPtr<void>') */
}

Demo

That idea crossed my mind as well, but this approach would require me to: a) Declare the Base class virtual (reducing the efficiency) and b) Reimplement all the different constructors. Hence, I'll go with the other answer, which is sort of a 'partial class specialization'. Thank you very much anyway.
